# Intellij IDEA gives 302 when signing into Youtrack

Tags: intellij-idea, youtrack

I am creating a new server in Intellij IDEA and choosing youtrack. Every tie I hit test, I get a `http 302`

[image: Issue]

I have tried cutting off both the `/youtrack` and the `/dashboard` part of the URL and have even tried taking off the *s* in `https` I am assured that my username and password are correct, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: A 302 is a server-side "Found" response.  If you hit that link directly and observe the request cycle (for instance in Chrome's Network tab), you should get back the resource that the server is going to send you to for the appropriate resource.  You'd have to observe that as we can't say if it's a redirect policy shooting you down or you may have mistyped the resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same problem. 
If you are using the free Cloud Service, SSL isn't used, so you have to use only http not https

Comment: I think they've changed it to SSL only, what works for me now is : "https://myteam.myjetbrains.com/youtrack"

Answer (score 8):

First of all URL of your InCloud server should be finished with /youtrack
[image]

Check, also, please
1. that your subscription is actual
2. you do not have any proxy server in the middle

BTW, what is your IDEA version?

Comment: I am not sure of what version I have. I believe it is 14.0.2